# changing Instance of 'Barcode' to String

Tags: flutter, dart

So i create a qr Scanner and i manage to finished it and give me a result, but as i print the result it give me

```
'Instance of 'Barcode'
```

feedback

Here's my code

```
 Future _openScanner(BuildContext context) async {
        final result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => Scanner()));
        _result = result.toString();
      }
```

How I show on my app

```
Text(
           _result != null ? _result : 'Hi, Raisa',
              style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(
              0xFFE1C884),
             // fontFamily: 'Saveur',
             fontWeight: FontWeight
               .bold,
           fontSize: 20.sp
          ),
 )
```

My QR View Code

```
QRView(
              key: _qrKey,
              overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(borderColor: Colors.white),
              onQRViewCreated: (QRViewController controller) {
                this._controller = controller;
                controller.scannedDataStream.listen((val) {
                  // print(val.toString());
                  if (mounted) {
                    _controller.dispose();
                    Navigator.pop(context,val);
                  }
                });
              }),
```

Comment: toString() method will return the object name, which is `'Instance of 'Barcode'`

Comment: @Mayank but if i dont add that itll be error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/qr_code_scanner/latest/qr_code_scanner/Barcode-class.html), you should be using `val.code` to get the string value of the barcode.

```dart
onQRViewCreated: (QRViewController controller) {
  this._controller = controller;
  controller.scannedDataStream.listen((val) {
    if (mounted) {
      _controller.dispose();
      Navigator.pop(context, val.code);
    }
  });
}),
```

In the future, if you are having issues with a package, make sure you include what and where the [package](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) is. That way, potential answerers don't have to go hunting for it and guess which package you are using. You will get more and better answers more quickly that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
 Future _openScanner(BuildContext context) async {
        final result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => Scanner()));
        _result = result.getValue;
      }
```

```
class Barcode{
String? value;
...
String get getValue{
    return value;
  }
...
}
```

```
QRView(
              key: _qrKey,
              overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(borderColor: Colors.white),
              onQRViewCreated: (QRViewController controller) {
                this._controller = controller;
                controller.scannedDataStream.listen((val) {
                  // print(val.toString());
                  if (mounted) {
                    _controller.dispose();
                    value = val;
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }
                });
              }),

}
```

Comment: error on `value = val;`

A value of type 'Barcode' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.

Comment: @Caramel From what info you gave, that's as far as I can go. You should do `value=val;`, where val is the String returned from your Barcode reader,

Answer (score 0):

There's an incorrection there

1. add this :

`final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');`
`Barcode result;`

2. add this on the QRview

```
QRView(
              key: _qrKey,
              overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(borderColor: Colors.white),
              onQRViewCreated: (QRViewController controller) {
                this._controller = controller;
                controller.scannedDataStream.listen((val) {
                  // print(val.toString());
                  if (mounted) {
                    _controller.dispose();
                    value = val; //this
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }
                });
              }),
}
```

3. when about to show or print

   a. if you want to print the type of the Barcode simply add (.format)
   b. if you want to print the code of the barcode simply add (.code)